# How many squares is this rectangle on the Clue board?

Tags: cluedo

See the photo for context. My boys had a dispute about moving through this rectangle, whether it counts as one square or whether it should be thought of as containing smaller squares. [image: clue rectangle]

Do the rules address this?

Comment: Going by graphics alone, I'd argue that if no grid is drawn inside the area then it should be considered a single square. If the rules intended that the room be made of squares, I would have expected them to draw such squares in.

Comment: I would argue that it ought to be treated like a room, given it has the graphical characteristics of a room - the orange-ish walls, the openings, the top-down 3d look.

Comment: Judging by your diagram this appears to be the room in the center of the board.  The envelope with the correct solution is supposed to be placed there.  This room is not accessible.

Comment: Really? Quote the rules on this, and make your comment an answer.

Answer (score 9):

Movement occurs **between** rooms, not across them. As soon as you reach a room, the movement phase ends. As soon as you start to move, you must leave the room to do so.

The [rules](http://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/clue_%282002%29.pdf) don't address this directly, but there are clear implications that a room is considered a single location (not a square, but similar) when it comes to movement. For example:

> It is possible that your opponents might block any and all doors and trap you in a room. If this happens, you must wait for someone to move and unblock a door so you can leave!

Also,

> You may not forfeit a turn to remain in a particular Room.

If a room constitutes of multiple squares, it's possible to move your character without leaving the room. It seems to me that this is not in the spirit of the game.

Comment: The biggest question this raises is this: If a room is a single square, how can multiple players be in the same room simultaneously?

Comment: I would argue that it apparently is a lot bigger than the squares, but you raise a valid point. Allow me to write some addendum to my answer.